# Ethernet connectivity lost on one port by working on others

Tags: networking, ethernet, ports

I currently connect to a PLC via a fixed remote IP, this is then routed to a local IP on that network and has specific port allocated for access. I recently could not access this device although it was able to send out emails on another port. Simply unplugging and plugging the ethernet cable back in at the remote end fixed the problem.

What could be the cause of the lost communication? What does the unplugging/plugging back in of the cable do?

Additional detail. we currently have 90+ PLCs operating in quite remote location, most of which have have cellular routers connected - not problems connecting (other than 3G sunset upgrades). A small number are connected through our clients router/network where they assign a fixed IP on there subnet with specific ports opened for us to access our systems. This works OK for 8 units, no problem connecting. Two of these with one client, remains connected for several day, but then looses has  connection and the way we have reconnect is to unplug and plug in the ethernet cable on the PLC - everything works. The odd thing is that these two sites go through different IPs.

As these sites are remote unplugging and plugging in the cable is not very practical and results in control and data loss. I don't have any control of the remote network. Is there a way/method that can be used by the administrators of those routers that would be equivalent of the physical action?

They tell us the connections are good but I would dispute that.

Thanks
Paul

Comment: That description doesn't really communicate a clear picture of how your network is set up. Maybe consider drawing a network diagram and label the IP addresses associated with each Ethernet port.

Comment: @Spiff Not really needed. PLC devices aren't, typically very stable. Last time I've used a couple, reconnecting once in a fortnight was the norm.

Comment: I don't know that PLCs are unstable, from my own experience, but others here clearly do. Unless you can present more information, I don't think we can give any better answer at this time. If you do have more info, preset it by editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

> What could be the cause of the lost communication?

PLCs are just unstable. What you report here isn't unusual.

> What does the unplugging/plugging back in of the cable do?

It resets the device, that's all.